Compare HTML of div in a cypress test with a expected HTML
In one cypress test I just want to check if the server side generated HTML is correct, so I just want to compare it with my expected HTML:
I can do it like this which works fine:
cy.get("table").eq(0).should("have.html",
"<tbody>"
+ "<tr><td><b>Minimale Punktzahl</b>"
+ "</td><td>3</td></tr>"
+ "<tr><td><b>Maximale Punktzahl</b></td><td>10</td></tr>" 
+ "</tbody>"
);

But i would rather like to compare it logically and not as a byte sequence.
This should work too, but it doesn't:
 cy.get(".ktable").eq(0).should("have.html",
            `<tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Minimale Punktzahl</b></td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Maximale Punktzahl</b></td>
                        <td>10</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>`);

It doesn't work because of the whitespace which the server side removes.
I searched for some library which just normalizes the HTML before comparison, but I havn't found anything.
There must be a JS Lib for comparing two HTML snippets logically.

please check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-html for example

Rather than compare HTML structures, which will be very brittle, would it not make more sense to check that the text labels exist, and/or the expected values?

@RoryMcCrossan You are right. Usually you should obey best practice about "text content" in cypress ( https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Text-Content ). But in my case I want to check the server-side generated HTML

Since the first example is passing, I assume the generated HTML is minified (spaces removed).
You could do the same for the second example
cy.get(".ktable").eq(0).should("have.html",
   `<tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Minimale Punktzahl</b></td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Maximale Punktzahl</b></td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>`.replace(/\s/g, ''))   // remove the spaces with global regex 

or with a tagFunction
const transform = (s) => s.replace(/\s/g, '');

cy.get(".ktable").eq(0).should("have.html", 
  transform`<tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Minimale Punktzahl</b></td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Maximale Punktzahl</b></td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>`)


This solution might work sometimes but it doesn't work for more complex scenarios. whitespace is sometimes significant in HTML, sometimes it is not. I will go with the chai-html lib commented in the question

Yes, chai-html does this as well, just more opaquely. Use my solution or a variation if you want to control exactly what you are comparing.

Or change your expectations, as Rory McCrossen says, an e2e test should not care about the HTML (which is an implemtation detail and can change) but instead should care about what is delivered in the browser.

Yep, you are all right. But here the exact HTML is generated on the server and I check it on the client in a black box test. Just let me do it. please :-)
